# How to get all (non-disabled) user SIDs via Windows API?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, sid

I'm looking for a way to retrieve all user SIDs on a system via the Windows API.

Retrieving all user SIDs can be done with via `wmic useraccount get sid`. Is there a way of getting this information via the Windows API instead?

Additionally, the `wmic` command returns the SIDs of all accounts, including disabled accounts - `wmic useraccount get disabled,sid` will show which accounts are disabled. It would be a bonus if a solution could advise on how to retrieve the SIDs of accounts that are not disabled, but this is not crucial.

Comment: NetUserEnum -> NetUserGetInfo is one way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function:

```
NET_API_STATUS NET_API_FUNCTION NetUserEnum(
  LPCWSTR servername,
  DWORD   level,
  DWORD   filter,
  LPBYTE  *bufptr,
  DWORD   prefmaxlen,
  LPDWORD entriesread,
  LPDWORD totalentries,
  PDWORD  resume_handle
);
```

with `servername = NULL` to enumerate local computer accounts, then use:

```
BOOL LookupAccountNameW(
  LPCWSTR       lpSystemName,
  LPCWSTR       lpAccountName,
  PSID          Sid,
  LPDWORD       cbSid,
  LPWSTR        ReferencedDomainName,
  LPDWORD       cchReferencedDomainName,
  PSID_NAME_USE peUse
);
```

to retrieve **SID**'s.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountnamew for details and examples.

In function `NetUserEnum`, setting the parameter `level=1` will return detailed information about user accounts, and the `bufptr` parameter will point to an array of `USER_INFO_1` structures.

Examining the member `usri1_flags` of structure `USER_INFO_1` with mask `UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE` give the status of account.

Following RbMm comment, note that specifying in function `NetUserEnum` the parameter `level=3`, the `bufptr` parameter will point to an array of `USER_INFO_3` structures, that contains user **RID**'s.
The member `usri3_user_id` contains the relative ID (RID) of the user, and the member  `usri3_primary_group_id` contains the RID of the Primary Global Group for the user. Using these values you don't need to call `LookupAccountNameW`.

The efficiency is boosted using suggestions from RbMm in the comments below.

Comment: **not need** use `LookupAccountNameW` in this case. because we have user *RID* here already. `NetUserEnum` more heave function compare `NetQueryDisplayInformation` - need use it only if we need **more** info, than returned by `NetQueryDisplayInformation`

Comment: `LookupAccountNameW` at all very bad design. even i we need query only single name not good use it. internal it call. `LsaOpenPolicy` + `LsaLookupNames2` + `LsaClose`. note that `LsaLookupNames2` allocate memory for you already. when you call `LookupAccountNameW` - you need provide self buffers (and unknown at begin size). the `LookupAccountNameW` copy memory to your buffers and free original. so even in single name query more easy and efficient call `LsaLookupNames2` direct. when you do multiple queries(say dump ACL, token groups) - always better call `LsaLookupNames2` direct and **once**.

Comment: but in this concrete case we not need even `LsaLookupNames2` because we have additional context here - user (RID) - so for get it full SID - enough at begin query domain SID, allocate new SID with additional subauthory and then set user RID to this final subauthory.. of course if you want **efficient** and fast code

Comment: @RbMm You're right. I mention your comments in the answer.

Comment: and `NetUserEnum` vs `NetQueryDisplayInformation`: internall its call `SamConnect` + `SamEnumerateDomainsInSamServer` + `SamLookupDomainInSamServer` + `SamOpenDomain` - this is common part. then `NetQueryDisplayInformation` call `SamQueryDisplayInformation` when `NetUserEnum` - `SamEnumerateUsersInDomain` + `SamOpenUser` + `SamQueryInformationUser` - much more. and every call - this is remote and very heavy call

Comment: this is because even msdn write *To quickly enumerate user, computer, or global group account information, call the NetQueryDisplayInformation function.* - if we need only information which returned by `NetQueryDisplayInformation` better use it. if we need more information on User or change information for user - we need use `NetUserEnum`. of course most efficient use direct SamXXX api (all another api based on it) (for not reopen the same handles many times), but as usual it not documented.

Comment: @RbMm Usual enough for MS... Anyway this isn't a very popular development area that's one of the reason of poor knowledge and documentation. Thank-you for the very in-deep explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

A simple one is with [NetQueryDisplayInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netquerydisplayinformation)

Test sample (Windows 10, VS 2015) =>

```
NET_API_STATUS NetStatus;
DWORD dwIndex = 0;
DWORD dwEntriesRequested = 0xFFFFFFFF;
DWORD dwPreferredMaximumLength = 0xFFFFFFFF;
DWORD dwReturnedEntryCount;
PVOID pNDU = NULL;
do {
    NetStatus = NetQueryDisplayInformation(NULL, 1, dwIndex, dwEntriesRequested, dwPreferredMaximumLength, &dwReturnedEntryCount, &pNDU);
    if (NetStatus != NERR_Success && NetStatus != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
        break;
    for (int i = 0; i < dwReturnedEntryCount; i++)
    {
        PNET_DISPLAY_USER NetDisplayUser = (PNET_DISPLAY_USER)(((LPBYTE)pNDU) + sizeof(NET_DISPLAY_USER) * i);              
        PSID pSID = ConvertNameToSID(NetDisplayUser->usri1_name);
        LPWSTR pszSid = NULL;
        ConvertSidToStringSid(pSID, &pszSid);
        BOOL bIsAccountDisabled = ((NetDisplayUser->usri1_flags & UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) != 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        WCHAR wsBuffer[MAX_PATH];           
        wsprintf(wsBuffer, L"%4.4ld %-20.20ws SID : %ws - Disabled : %ws - Comment : %ws\n",
            NetDisplayUser->usri1_next_index,
            NetDisplayUser->usri1_name,
            pszSid,
            (bIsAccountDisabled ? L"True" : L"False"),
            NetDisplayUser->usri1_comment
        );
        LocalFree(pSID);

        OutputDebugString(wsBuffer);
        dwIndex = NetDisplayUser->usri1_next_index;                 
    }
    NetApiBufferFree(pNDU);
} while (NetStatus == ERROR_MORE_DATA);

PSID ConvertNameToSID(LPTSTR lpszName)
{
    WCHAR wszDomainName[256];
    DWORD dwSizeDomain = sizeof(wszDomainName) / sizeof(TCHAR);
    DWORD dwSizeSid = 0;
    SID_NAME_USE sidName;
    LookupAccountName(NULL, lpszName, NULL, &dwSizeSid, wszDomainName, &dwSizeDomain, &sidName);
    PSID pSid;
    pSid = (PSID)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSizeSid);
    LookupAccountName(NULL, lpszName, pSid, &dwSizeSid, wszDomainName, &dwSizeDomain, &sidName);
    return pSid;
}
```

Comment: use `ConvertNameToSID` is very not efficient here. you have `usri1_user_id` - (RID) of the user - so need simply append it to domain SID.

Comment: No. See MS samples : they do exactly like that... (in Gina, among others)

Comment: no, this is not efficient. very not efficient. you have user rid - ise it

Comment: No, you don't have Domain SID to concatenate it. See the old Gina sample from SDK...

Comment: we need first got  Domain SID - **once** and than use it - simply append user RID to this SID. i not need to look bad examples

Comment: So it is more code... Always use MS SDK samples to make your code... (I still use SDK 16-bit code from 1990 which stll works on Windows 10...)

Comment: i not need use bad and not efficient samples. again - need be able write efficient code. we have RID - need use it. one call to LookupAccountName - this is LsaOpenPolicy(remote call to lsass) -> LsaLookupNames2(remote call to lsass) -> SamLookupNamesInDomain (inside lsass) -> LsaClose(remote call to lsass). (i assume that lsass hold open SAM for not call SamOpenDomain every time)

Comment: very many MS examples wrong and not efficient. and again need understand - where use some api. if we need query 1 user name without additional context (like here) - use `LookupAccountName` ok. if we need use 2+ names - this is already bad. need use `LsaLookupNames2`. but if we have user RID, like in this case - not need use even `LsaLookupNames2` - need append this RID to domain SID

Comment: *Tell MS that their code is 'inefficient" :-)* - i tell you that **your** code is not efficient

Answer (score 0):

for enumerate user accounts in SAM (Security Account Manager) database we can use or `NetQueryDisplayInformation` (more fast) or `NetUserEnum` (if we need more detail user information). or SAM api (fastest, include [*ntsam.h*](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntsam.h) and link with *samlib.lib* )

note that if we have user (RID) we not need use *LookupAccountName* - this is very not efficient in this case (many heavy remote calls internal - `LsaOpenPolicy`, `LsaLookupNames2`, `LsaClose` . internal `LsaLookupNames2` use anyway SAM api [`SamLookupNamesInDomain`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntsam.h#L448)).
really all what we need - first get domain *SID* and than append user *RID* to it. get domain SID we can by `LsaQueryInformationPolicy` with `PolicyAccountDomainInformation` for SID of the account domain (computer) - always exist and with `PolicyDnsDomainInformation` or `PolicyPrimaryDomainInformation` for get *SID* of the primary domain (exist only if computer part of Domain)

```
void PrintUsersInDomain(PUNICODE_STRING ServerName, PSID DomainSid)
{
    PWSTR szServerName = 0;

    if (ServerName)
    {
        if (ULONG Length = ServerName->Length)
        {
            szServerName = ServerName->Buffer;
            // if not null terminated
            if (Length + sizeof(WCHAR) < ServerName->MaximumLength || *(PWSTR)((PBYTE)szServerName + Length))
            {
                szServerName = (PWSTR)alloca(Length + sizeof(WCHAR));
                memcpy(szServerName, ServerName->Buffer, Length);
                *(PWSTR)((PBYTE)szServerName + Length) = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    UCHAR SubAuthorityCount = *GetSidSubAuthorityCount(DomainSid);
    ULONG DestinationSidLength = GetSidLengthRequired(SubAuthorityCount + 1);

    PSID UserSid = alloca(DestinationSidLength);
    CopySid(DestinationSidLength, UserSid, DomainSid);
    ++*GetSidSubAuthorityCount(UserSid);
    PULONG pRid = GetSidSubAuthority(UserSid, SubAuthorityCount);

    PVOID Buffer;
    ULONG Index = 0, ReturnedEntryCount;

    NET_API_STATUS status;

    do 
    {
        switch (status = NetQueryDisplayInformation(szServerName, 1, Index, 
            64, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, &ReturnedEntryCount, &Buffer))
        {
        case NOERROR:
        case ERROR_MORE_DATA:
            if (ReturnedEntryCount)
            {
                PNET_DISPLAY_USER pndu = (PNET_DISPLAY_USER)Buffer;

                do 
                {
                    //if (!(pndu->usri1_flags & UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE))
                    {
                        *pRid = pndu->usri1_user_id;

                        PWSTR szSid;
                        if (ConvertSidToStringSidW(UserSid, &szSid))
                        {
                            DbgPrint("\t[%08x] %S %S\n", pndu->usri1_flags, pndu->usri1_name, szSid);
                            LocalFree(szSid);
                        }
                    }

                    Index = pndu->usri1_next_index;

                } while (pndu++, --ReturnedEntryCount);
            }

            NetApiBufferFree(Buffer);
        }
    } while (status == ERROR_MORE_DATA);
}

void PrintUsersInDomain_fast(PUNICODE_STRING ServerName, PSID DomainSid)
{
    SAM_HANDLE ServerHandle, DomainHandle = 0;

    //SAM_SERVER_ENUMERATE_DOMAINS|SAM_SERVER_LOOKUP_DOMAIN
    NTSTATUS status = SamConnect(ServerName, &ServerHandle, SAM_SERVER_LOOKUP_DOMAIN, 0);

    DbgPrint("SamConnect(%wZ) = %x\n", ServerName, status);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        status = SamOpenDomain(ServerHandle, DOMAIN_READ|DOMAIN_EXECUTE, DomainSid, &DomainHandle);

        SamCloseHandle(ServerHandle);
    }

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        UCHAR SubAuthorityCount = *GetSidSubAuthorityCount(DomainSid);
        ULONG DestinationSidLength = GetSidLengthRequired(SubAuthorityCount + 1);

        PSID UserSid = alloca(DestinationSidLength);
        CopySid(DestinationSidLength, UserSid, DomainSid);
        ++*GetSidSubAuthorityCount(UserSid);
        PULONG pRid = GetSidSubAuthority(UserSid, SubAuthorityCount);

        PVOID Buffer;

        ULONG Index = 0, TotalAvailable, TotalReturned, ReturnedEntryCount;

        do 
        {
            if (0 <= (status = SamQueryDisplayInformation(DomainHandle,
                DomainDisplayUser,
                Index,
                2,
                0x10000,
                &TotalAvailable,
                &TotalReturned,
                &ReturnedEntryCount,
                &Buffer)))
            {
                if (ReturnedEntryCount)
                {
                    PSAM_DISPLAY_USER psdu = (PSAM_DISPLAY_USER)Buffer;
                    do 
                    {
                        //if (!(psdu->AccountControl & USER_ACCOUNT_DISABLED))
                        {
                            *pRid = psdu->Rid;

                            PWSTR szSid;
                            if (ConvertSidToStringSidW(UserSid, &szSid))
                            {
                                DbgPrint("\t[%08x] %wZ %S\n", psdu->AccountControl, &psdu->AccountName, szSid);
                                LocalFree(szSid);
                            }
                        }

                        Index = psdu->Index;

                    } while (psdu++, --ReturnedEntryCount);
                }
                SamFreeMemory(Buffer);
            }
        } while (status == STATUS_MORE_ENTRIES);

        SamCloseHandle(DomainHandle);
    }
}

void PrintUsers()
{
    LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle;

    LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes = { sizeof(ObjectAttributes) };
    NTSTATUS status;
    if (0 <= (status = LsaOpenPolicy(0, &ObjectAttributes, POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, &PolicyHandle)))
    {
        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PPOLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO pddi;
            PPOLICY_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN_INFO padi;
        };

        if (0 <= LsaQueryInformationPolicy(PolicyHandle, PolicyAccountDomainInformation, &buf))
        {
            DbgPrint("DomainName=<%wZ>\n", &padi->DomainName);
            if (padi->DomainSid) 
            {
                PrintUsersInDomain_fast(&padi->DomainName, padi->DomainSid);
                PrintUsersInDomain(&padi->DomainName, padi->DomainSid);
            }
            LsaFreeMemory(buf);
        }

        if (0 <= LsaQueryInformationPolicy(PolicyHandle, PolicyDnsDomainInformation, &buf))
        {
            DbgPrint("DomainName=<%wZ>\n", &pddi->Name);
            if (pddi->Sid) 
            {
                PrintUsersInDomain_fast(&pddi->Name, pddi->Sid);
                PrintUsersInDomain(&pddi->Name, pddi->Sid);
            }
            LsaFreeMemory(buf);
        }
        LsaClose(PolicyHandle); 
    }
}

typedef struct SAM_DISPLAY_USER {
    ULONG Index;
    ULONG Rid;
    ULONG AccountControl; /* User account control bits */
    UNICODE_STRING AccountName;
    UNICODE_STRING AdminComment;
    UNICODE_STRING FullName;
} *PSAM_DISPLAY_USER;
```